# Adobe AIR and Google Play incompatible device obstruction

Tags: android, air, adobe

How to obstruct Adobe Air incompatible devices to don't show apk on Google Play (on this devices)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to native manifests "Main-app.xml" there you can add required restrictions. For example minimum SDK version etc. Google Play will automatically only show your app to devices what has passed your requirements